# JMonkey 3 Asset Cache

Tags: java, caching, assets, jmonkeyengine

I'm in the process of learning JMonkey for the purpose of building a framework on top of it.

1. How do I manage the asset cache?
2. Is there any way to clear it?
3. Is there any way to delete a specific item from the cache?

I've been looking at the assetMaager in the application object and there does not appear to be any cache methods.  i'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AssetManager is an Interface which provides no direct way to tamper with the cache. Which actual class you could depend on the operating system you load your application on.

However there appears to be only one class Interfacing asset manager:

com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager

That class does provide ways to manage the cache. Try casting you assetmanager to that class and then using the extra functionality that provides you.